# A question about module

Tags: modules

Assume R is commutative. Show that an R-module M is irreducible if and only if M is isomorphic (as an R-Module) to R/I where I is a maximal ideal of R. 
If I remove the hypothesis that R is communtative, is it result still true?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true, if you replace ideal by **right ideal**.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_module#cite_ref-0